# how do I import a vector path from Inkscape into Gimp?

Tags: gimp, inkscape, svg

I'd like to take an SVG clipart, pull out particular paths from it, and bring them into Gimp and use them to create selections and/or to stroke.  Nothing I've tried seems to work -- even though Gimp seems to be able to import SVG paths, it doesn't seem to work from files from Inskcape or the SVG's before bringing them into Inkscape.

Is there any trick to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When selecting a path in Inkscape and al its points using the path tool (F2) then use a regular copy + paste action in Gimp does the trick for me.

The path shows up in the Gimp paths dialog and i am able to stroke the path.

Answer (score 2):

After you're done creating an SVG in Inkscape, you can just select the clipart and copy it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then paste it in GIMP using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. It is as simple as that.

However, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from Inkscape and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in GIMP may not work sometimes. In that case, you might want to copy it from Inkscape just like before and then go to GIMP, Go to `Edit > Paste As > Layer` if you want it to be pasted into your current working canvas as a layer or `Edit > Paste As > Image` if you want to paste it as an image in a new canvas. You can then copy it from there and paste it in your canvas.

Comment: Hi Suhas Bharadwaj, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!